# expressiveness of turing machines

Tags: number-theory

How does one determine the expressiveness of turing machines? 
In my class to prove expressiveness of say a DFA.  What we do is demonstrate that all loop-less transition systems can be expressed with a DFA.  By transitivity my professor claims we have just demonstrated the expressiveness of a DFA.

Q is how does one prove the expressiveness of a TM?